# why cannot add foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `"label"` with 2 columns:

```
_LABEL_ID (varchar)
_LENGTH   (varchar)
```

This table already has data in it!

And I have several other Tables `"a", "b", "c",` etc.

these tables have the column `_LABEL_ID` (varchar). These table are not empty

On delete of any row from tables `a, b, c,` ...etc., then delete its label from the "`label`" table. I tried to add foreign key to "`label`" referenced to table `"a"` for doing this (just to test it), but getting the same error like in this question:

[can't add foreign key in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758106/cant-add-foreign-key-in-mysql)

In my case I have `InnoDB` engine for all tables, unique names FK's, same data types.

Now I exported `label` rows, then emptied the `label` table, adding foreign key to it referenced to `"a"` table  works just fine. If i import the rows again to the `label` table, I get the same error which I got when try to add foreign key.

the rows in `label` table belong to different tables (a, b, c, ..etc). is this the cause of the error?

i do this using MySQL Workbench

EDIT: the real SQL Statement and the Error Message:

```
ALTER TABLE `cal_view_db`.`dbo_pub_label` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_dbo_pub_label_treenode`
  FOREIGN KEY (`_LABEL_ID` )
  REFERENCES `cal_view_db`.`dbo_system_treenode` (`_NAME_ID` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `fk_dbo_pub_label_treenode_idx` (`_LABEL_ID` ASC) ;
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cal_view_db`.`#sql-10cc_4a`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dbo_pub_label_treenode` FOREIGN KEY (`_LABEL_ID`) REFERENCES `dbo_system_treenode` (`_NAME_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `cal_view_db`.`dbo_pub_label` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_dbo_pub_label_treenode`
  FOREIGN KEY (`_LABEL_ID` )
  REFERENCES `cal_view_db`.`dbo_system_treenode` (`_NAME_ID` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `fk_dbo_pub_label_treenode_idx` (`_LABEL_ID` ASC)

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `dbo_pub_label` (
  `_LABEL_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `_LENGTH` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_LABEL_ID`),
  KEY `fk_dbo_pub_label_1_idx` (`_LABEL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

many thanks

p.s: sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Are you getting the same error as in the other question? Did you try the same solution(s) suggested there?

Comment: @atk, yes i tried the same solutions suggested there. as i said, if i empty the table "label", i can add an FK to it, but if i import the data again, i get an error( cannot update due to FK...etc)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the foreign keys are unique throughout the db?

Comment: foreign key names are unique!

Comment: What is your FK exactly. (In general some code/data samples are helpfull)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does seem that your problem is that the data in label belongs to multiple tables.

If I am not mistaken then a **FK** tells the DB to check in the referenced table for every value in the **FK** Table.

Here, you have labels from `a` and `b` and `c` and `d`. When the DB goes to verify the **FK** it will not find the data in **label** that corresponds to the data in `b,c,d,etc`. It will only find  the ones that are in `a`.

This is why your error comes up both when you try and create the table and when you try to reload the data to the table. All records in a **FK column** must have a match in the referenced table. (Here that is `label -> FK -> a`)

Comment: ok, what is the solution then? adding many FK's to every TABLE has a reference to "Label" table all in one statement will work?

Comment: You could add them one by one. But the FK needs to be from the `a` table to the `label` table. (`a -> FK -> label`). That way each entry in the FK table `a`, exists in the referenced table `label`.

Comment: but i need the FK from "label" to "a".

Comment: Why are all the tables a,b,c,... separated?